# Authentification with AWS Coginito built-in web page

Tags: amazon-cognito

I am building a authentification with AWS Cognito built-in web page.

(I am using Cognito User Pool and Identity Pool without any other provider)

The Cognito webpage return me a token (idtoken) and I put it cookie.

When I try to use this token to get credential, with the following code :

```
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
  IdentityPoolId: 'eu-west-1:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  Logins: {
    'cognito-idp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/eu-west-XXXXXX':
     CookieHelper.getCookie("session-id")
  }
});

AWS.config.credentials.getId(...);
```

I get this error :

```
Error: Invalid login token. Missing a required claim: aud
```

How can I solve this problem?

Did I miss some steps between to get credentials?

May be I miss somthing in Cognito configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the wrong token.

The build-in webpage return 2 token : One for session-token and one for id-token.

With the other token, I can get credential.

Hope that will help some one.